# Use COALESCE within SUM in MySQL SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following tables:

```
Table users
id  name     base_discount
1   jack     10
2   michael  20
3   richard  30

Table item
id  name     category_id  price
1   hammer   1            10
2   knife    2            15
3   spoon    2            12
4   plate    3            20
5   tree     4            400

Table category
id  name
1   tools
2   kitchen
3   dishes
4   garden

Table discount_category
id  user_id  category_id  discount
1   1        1            20
2   1        3            25
3   3        3            10
4   1        2            15

Table discount_item
id  user_id  item_id  discount
1   2        1        50
2   1        2        50
```

Now what I want to achieve. I want to attach the discount per item that a user has to the correct item. If that is not available (NULL) I want to attach the discount per category that a user has. And if that is not available (NULL), I want to attach the base discount that a user has. With the discount I then calculate the new price of the item. However, when I try using COALESCE() within SUM() I get a syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

Below is my current query:

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, category.id, 
category.name AS category_name, item.price, SUM((100 -
COALESCE(
(
    SELECT discount_item.discount
    FROM discount_item
    INNER JOIN users ON discount_item.user_id = users.id
    WHERE users.id = '1' AND discount_item.item_id = item.id
),
(
    SELECT discount_category.discount
    FROM discount_category
    INNER JOIN users ON discount_category.user_id = users.id
    WHERE users.id = '1' AND discount_category.category_id = item.category_id
),
(
    SELECT users.base_discount
    FROM users
    WHERE users.id = '1'
)
)) / 100 * item.price) AS new_price,
FROM item
INNER JOIN category ON item.category_id = category.id;
```

Please also see the below link for an SQL Fiddle (couldn't do it on sqlfiddle.com as it wouldn't load). In the example I have appended a suffix to each table name.
http://rextester.com/LCCKSD59098

Comment: Not bad, but see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You are going a `sum` without `group by`. Is it intentional?

Comment: @Strawberry Please see http://rextester.com/JAQS56832. I'll add it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma after `new_price` and before `FROM ITEM`, hence the error.

[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/JKUR41640)

- Do not select other columns in select if you are not using them in group by, as in other relational RDBMS, you will get error.
- Also use `alias` for table names for better readibily and to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks, the comma fixed the syntax error. Now on to debug why it is only displaying one row of data. Even though doing the COALESCE without the sum (selecting only the discount percentage) does display multiple rows..

Comment: That is because `sum` is an aggregate function. I guess somehow in MYSQL, you are not getting error but in other RDBMS you will get error as you are selecting columns, like item.id,item.name without using them in group by. If you need that, then add `group by item.id, item.name, category.id, 
category.name, item.price`  to your query.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it!